# How to Bulk update or Upsert in mongodb with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bulkupdate

I need to update 3000+ bulk records in a collection by using mongoDB bulk update method, but It is inserting single records at a time.

I need to insert as a bulk. kindly suggest better way

```
     function bulkGl(DataArray){
  var bulk = Transaction.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
  for(i in DataArray){
    if(typeof DataArray[i].convertedValue !== NaN){
      var Data =  { "currency_conversions":[{
        "converted_value" : DataArray[i].convertedValue
       }]};
       var query =  { testid : DataArray[i].testid};
       bulk.find(query).upsert().update( Data)
  console.log('statusdata',Data);
  }
}
bulk.execute(function(err,res){
  console.log(err,data);
});
}
```

Comment: One method can be 1.Grab all documents that satisfy you conditions 2.Process/Update those Documents while it's in array of Js 3. Perform Bulk Insert by `insertMany`.  As it does bulk insert it overrides the document present in that collection.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `updateMany()` function instead of `update()`